# Overriding <ui:define>

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, templating

Is there a way to override the `<ui:define>` that JSF templating offers?

For instance file `main.xhtml`, that includes a template file, contains:

```
<ui:define name="title">SomeTitle</ui:define>
<ui:define name="menu"><ui:include src="path_to_menu_1"/></ui:define>
<ui:define name="content">content_code_goes_here</ui:define>
```

If I want to create a `main2.xhtml` file that is identical to the `main.xhtml`, with the exception that it uses a different menu is there the possibility to do something like this:

```
<ui:include src="main.xhtml"/>
<ui:define name="menu"><ui:include src="path_to_menu_2"/></ui:define>
```

Where the `<ui:define name="menu">` overrides the tag with the same name attribute in `main.xhtml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just specify `main.xhtml` as template of `main2.xhtml`.

`main.xhtml`

```
<ui:composition template="sometemplate.xhtml" ...>
    <ui:define name="title">SomeTitle</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="menu"><ui:include src="path_to_menu_1"/></ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">content_code_goes_here</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

`main2.xhtml`

```
<ui:composition template="main.xhtml" ...>
    <ui:define name="menu"><ui:include src="path_to_menu_2"/></ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: I think I slowly start to understand the difference between ui:decorate and ui:composition - the explanation "jsf disregards everything outside of ui:composition" seems not enough - it seems as well that ui:decorate together with ui:define acts differently. E.g. your suggested solution will not work when you use everything you mentioned with ui:decorate instead of ui:composition. But you can use ui:decorate in the last step i.e. in main2.xhtml